# Cargue de información a postgre desde python

Tags: python, postgresql

Camaradas necesito un gran favor, necesito hacer el cargue de información de un dataframe a postgre y me sale este error, alguien sabe a qué se debe y/o como lo puedo solucionar.
Gracias a todos por su atención.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si estas en Windows hace uso de la herramienta de recortes y todo el código va como código no como imagen

Comment: EL código va como texto, por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/506778/edit) tu pregunta. Además, aparte de mostrar el error no sirve de mucho, pues necesitamos ver el código que usas para saber donde podría producirse el error, al igual que se necesita una forma de replicar el error por lo que debes de proporcionar datos de prueba (entrada y salida esperada). Lee [ask]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.